# Can this topology be improved?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I have been practicing with modeling and after a few tries I got to about this far to me it seems ok, but I wanted to ask if anyone has advice or methods, I want to hear what others think before I continue with the rest of it. The main thing that concerns me is the vertexes which to me seem messy, so I want to be sure.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]